# Are there any efficiency benefits to using `itertools.filterfalse()` as opposed to `filter(not function, iter)`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-itertools

If I want to find all numbers greater than 5 in `range(10)` using the `filter` function, I could do:

```py
result = filter(lambda x: x>5, range(10))
```

However, the `itertools` module has the `filterfalse` function, which as far as I can tell, would basically do

```py
result = filter(lambda x: not x>5, range(10))
```

Am I wrong about this? Is there any benefit to having such a function? Other functions like `islice` have some small advantages over conventional slicing, so I would assume that `filterfalse` would also have a niche use.

Comment: [The documentation for `filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#filter) calls `filterfalse` a "complementary function", so I guess it's there for convenience.

Comment: You can test it yourself using `timeit.Timer`

Comment: I think `filterfalse` is mostly for when you're not writing your own function, who's logic you could invert, but rather when you're using a pre-existing function that doesn't have an inverted version. For example, `str.isalpha`. While you could wrap it with `lambda s: not s.isalpha()`, using `filterfalse` might be a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

A quick benchmark with `timeit` module shows, that using `filter()` and `itertools.filterfalse()` has roughly the same performance. List comprehension is definitely faster though:

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import filterfalse

N = 10_000

def f1():
    return list(filter(lambda x: x>5, range(N)))

def f2():
    return list(filterfalse(lambda x: not x>5, range(N)))

def f3():
    return [i for i in range(N) if i > 5]


t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=10)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(), number=10)
t3 = timeit(lambda: f3(), number=10)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 2400G, Python 3.8):

```
0.018814088001818163
0.01380085300115752
0.007684074000280816
```

---

EDIT: Removing `not` from `filterfalse()`:

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import filterfalse

N = 10_000

def f1():
    return list(filter(lambda x: x>5, range(N)))

def f2():
    return list(filterfalse(lambda x: x<=5, range(N)))

def f3():
    return [i for i in range(N) if i > 5]


t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=10)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(), number=10)
t3 = timeit(lambda: f3(), number=10)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Prints:

```
0.01010196800052654
0.01007204300549347
0.005998152002575807
```

---

EDIT: benchmark with Perfplot:

```
import perfplot
from itertools import filterfalse


def f1_filter(r):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x>5, r))

def f2_filterfalse(r):
    return list(filterfalse(lambda x: x<=5, r))

def f3_comprehension(r):
    return [i for i in r if i > 5]

def setup(n):
    return range(n)

perfplot.show(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[f1_filter, f2_filterfalse, f3_comprehension],
    labels=['filter', 'filterfalse', 'comprehension'],
    n_range=[10**i for i in range(1, 7)],
    xlabel='N',
    logx=True,
    logy=True)
```

Shows:

[image]

Comment: That output is pretty different from what I see, and I suspect you copied the wrong output. `filterfalse` *beats* `filter` by a comfortable margin in your output, despite the test being stacked against it with the extra `not` being placed in the `filterfalse` test.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I removed the `not` from `filterfalse()` and changed it to  `x<=5`. Still, the result is +/- same (see my edit). What CPU do you use? PS: Don't worry about the downvote, it's how it goes here at SO :)

Comment: I don't know what CPU it is. Whatever ideone uses.

Comment: In your original output, the `filterfalse` version somehow takes about 73% the time of the `filter` version, despite doing more work. (If you thought the times were close, you might have gotten a 3 and an 8 mixed up when eyeballing the comparison.)

Comment: You might want to test with functions or methods that are implemented in C, rather than using functions written in Python, which will almost always be slower. You could try `(5).__lt__` as one, though I'm not sure if the method binding is going to slow things down.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I added another benchmark (Perfplot). Still, `filter` and `filterfalse` results are same and comprehension faster. The first, original benchmark was done yesterday, the computer was restarted meanwhile - maybe some background task influenced the results (0.018.. vs 0.013..).

Answer (score 0):

I think the itertools module mainly provides convenience functions. They allow you to quickly write (efficient) code. For example, let's say you have some function to test for a certain property, e.g. to test if an object is a string of more than 3 characters:

```py
def is_long_string(x):
    return isinstance(x, str) and len(x) > 3
```

Now if you want to filter all such strings from a list of objects, you could just write:

```py
input_objects = [1, 2, 3.14, 'foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'xyzzy']
long_strings = list(filter(is_long_string, input_objects))
```

However, if you would want to have all *other* objects, you'd have to write a `is_not_long_string()` function, or use a lambda function:

```py
not_long_strings = list(filter(lambda x: not is_long_string(x), input_objects))
```

Using itertools you could write this easier:

```py
not_long_strings = list(itertools.filterfalse(is_long_string, input_objects))
```

The `filterfalse()` function just provides the "reverse" operation of the built-in `filter()` function, i.e. something that is missing from the Python language itself.

Whether you want to use the first or second form (lambda or itertools) is a matter of personal preference.

In your example you're already using a lambda function, so the using itertools does not provide more readability or convenience in that case.

NB: Like Andrej has already demonstrated in his answer, performance is not the main reason to use itertools (rewriting the predicate function would probably result in better performance).